# Optimize connectionStrings in C# for Windows application

Tags: c#, optimization, sql-server-ce, connection-string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CalculatorEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/DomainModel.Model.csdl|res://*/DomainModel.Model.ssdl|res://*/DomainModel.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\Calculator.sdf&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

We are reading data in C# win app from a SQL Server CE 4.0 `.sdf` file. Problem is that first time when application is opening taking more then 30s but when application is opened then application working normally.

I think that problem is with the connection string and reading from `assembly`. Probably application searching so long for `.sdf` file before can find it.

How can I optimize `connectionStrings`? What can we do?

Comment: First things first. Instead of guessing what it could be that takes so long, *find out* what takes so long. Then fix that, instead of "fixing" random things.

Comment: The question is about SQL Server Compact, not SQL Server, very different products - for reasons see my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/08/faq-why-is-opening-my-sql-server.html